# Position of declaring label affecting output

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have written an assembly program to print a string:

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bx, HELLO_MSG

HELLO_MSG:
db "Hello World!", 0

mov ah, 0x0e

PRINT:
mov al, [bx]
cmp al, 0
je END
int 0x10
add bx, 0x1
jmp PRINT

END:

jmp $
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

when compiled using nasm it generated the following binary

```
BB 12 7C B4 0E 8A 07 3C 00 74 07 CD 10 83 C3 01 EB F3 48 65 6C 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21 00 EB FE 00 00 .... 00 00 55 AA
```

The output using qemu emulator is

[image: as it is clear the "ll" are replaced by other symbols]

as it is clear the "ll" are replaced by other symbols.

However if I move the `HELLO_MSG` label to bottom of the code just above `jmp $` the output is correct. I am unable to understand the reason behind this.

**EDIT:** I observed the following outputs on trying different strings in place of "Hello World" in the original code

**Case:** "Hellllo World" (notice extra 'l')

[image: the garbage letters appears on those two bytes only]

the garbage letters appears on those two bytes only

**Case:** "We are the gods"

[image: strangely the error disappeared!]

strangely the error disappeared!

**Case:** "We are the gods!" (notice '!')

[image: nothing printed, adding '!' did something terrible?]

nothing printed, adding '!' did something terrible?

**Case:** "Hello World" (notice !'!')

[image: removing '!' again did something terrible?]

removing '!' again did something terrible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put the string in the middle of the executable code. So the ASCII values are treated as instruction opcodes and perform some operation, which presumably happens to overwrite some bytes.

You should put the string at the end after the `jmp` instruction so that it isn't executed. Alternatively, you can add a `jmp` instruction before the string to jump over it.